# How to get the value of a dropdown menu returned by Paypal?

Tags: php, paypal, drop-down-menu, paypal-ipn

I'd like to know how to get the value of a dropdown menu with Paypal.

Everything works fine on Paypal's side, exept the fact that I don't know which subscription my members are paying for.

My form is as follow :

```
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Formula">Formula
    <select name="os0">
        <option value="Basic">Basic €5</option>
        <option value="Standard">Standard €10</option>
        <option value="VIP">VIP €20</option>
    </select>
```

How can I grab the selected value please ? I guess it's something like :

```
$_POST['os0']
```

...But this doesn't work. What am i missing please ?

Any help much apreciated, thanks !

Comment: Do you specify a return URL somewhere? It is in that return URL you could possibly `$_GET` the subscription they chose.

Comment: could you please be more specific about what value you ***do*** get, "this doesn't work" doesn't help very much.  Can you please do a `var_dump` of `$_POST['os0']
` and let us know what you get?

Comment: thx for the help guys. 
@Chase yes I have a return url, but I've also enlabed the auto-return feature in my paypal account, maybe that's the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your problem or not, but if you're not using HTTP POST, then the values won't show up in `$_POST['os0']`.  Try using `$_REQUEST['os0']` instead and see if you get the values that way.

You can read more about $_POST and $_REQUEST at [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).  You can read about how to set the form submission method at [the Mozilla docs](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/element/form):

```
<!-- Simple form which will send a POST request -->
<form action="" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

<!-- Form with fieldset, legend, and label -->
<form action="" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Title</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio"> <label for="radio">Click me</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

To learn more about HTTP [GET](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3) and [POST](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) in general, you can read their W3C specifications.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer.
Yes I'm using http post. 
I get the value of my custom field and it works. Don't know why I can't get the dropdown value... ($_POST['os0'] is empty)

Comment: @sun I don't think "empty" is a value in php, what are the ***exact*** results that you get by doing a `var_dump`?  Try `var_dump` the whole `$_POST` variable, not just that one value.  Also, you could probably use a browser development tool like Firebug to look at the POST data that way as well.

Comment: var_dump($_POST) returns nothing.
I tried to change the encodage of my IPN.php page, but nothing works.

Comment: @sun; have a look at the sample code at https://www.paypal.com/ipn -- right now you mention another file of which you haven't provided us with the code. You'd likely be better off using the sample code and then following the instructions as provided earlier.